# How to pass JobParameters to the Spring Batch Junit Test case JobLauncherTestUtils?

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am newbie to the Spring Batch, I have a following main program which I want to convert it into the test case using `jobLauncherTestUtils`. How we can do that?

I followed http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/testing.html, but I don't see any pointers. Please guide.

```
private void run() {
        String[] springConfig = { "spring/batch/jobs/job-extract-users.xml" };
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springConfig);

        JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
        Job job = (Job) context.getBean("testActualJob");

        try {
            JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("age", "20").toJobParameters();

            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, param);
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());
            System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getAllFailureExceptions());
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Done !!");
    }
```

Comment: See AppTest class in : https://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-unit-test-example/ for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the solution here:http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/test/JobLauncherTestUtils.html

```
@Test
    public void testMysqlToXMLWithParameters() throws Exception {
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("age", "20").toJobParameters();
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(jobParameters);
        Assert.assertEquals(jobExecution.getStatus(), BatchStatus.COMPLETED);
    }
```

Done !

Answer (score 5):

Quoted from the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/testing.html):-

> The launchJob() method is provided by the JobLauncherTestUtils class.
>   Also provided by the utils class is **launchJob(JobParameters)**, which
>   allows the test to give particular parameters.

Your code will look like below:-

```
JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("age", "20").toJobParameters();
 JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(param).getStatus();
```

Answer (score 4):

In case you want to run only a specific `step` that has job parameters, you can do it like the following:

```
JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder()
    .addString("language", "en_US")
    .toJobParameters();

JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep("stepName", param);
```

Answer (score 0):

just posting another approach for Junit -

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:request-jobs/spring-batch-config-jobs.xml"})
public class TestMyJob {

   @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "myJobName")
    private Job myJob;

    @Test
    public void testJob() throws Exception {
        JobParametersBuilder builder = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addLong("timestamp", System.currentTimeMillis());

        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(myJob, builder.toJobParameters());
        Assert.assertEquals("COMPLETED", jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());
    }

}
```

Comment: How to make this Batch Job test mock based Test cases ?

Comment: if you want to create a mock of job, then you will also need to write your own when and then logic around JobLauncher and JobExecution